# How do you do a $\Rightarrow$ with a slash through it in LaTeX (for "does not imply")

Tags: support, mathjax

I tried \cancel{\Rightarrow}, but perhaps I am installing the package improperly or something.

Thanks.

Comment: (This is not a support forum for LaTeX)

Comment: Oh, sorry -- I thought saw lots of LaTeX questions.  But I found the answer -- \not\Rightarrow $\not\Rightarrow$

Comment: @DavidLewis" That, unfortunately, gives bad spacing; but lucky for you there is a pre-built command.

Comment: **Please** ask this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a difference in asking for (la)tex support which is available on Math.SE, vs plain (la)tex support. You will see lots of questions of the former type on meta.math but probably very few upvoted ones of the latter.

Comment: The repost at TeX-SX has a little more context (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52827/86) making it clear that the question is about packages with MathJaX.  "How do I do X in MathJaX?" is **off-topic** on TeX-SX as it is *not* a question about TeX.  Please only refer genuine TeX (including, but not limited to, LaTeX) questions to TeX-SX.

Answer (score 17):

`\nRightarrow` gives $\nRightarrow$

**Added:** For a thorough discussion of `\implies` vs. `\Rightarrow`, see [this TeX.stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47063/491).

Unfortunately, it looks like `\centernot` is not supported in MathJax, nor is the solution using `\ooalign`

Answer (score 2):

You can always write: $$\lnot(\varphi\implies\psi)$$

Answer (score -1):

If you want to denote implication, it is usually best to use `\implies` from amsmath, which adjusts spacing (and dots).

Comment: How do you negate \implies? \not\implies gives poor alignment.  Tx.

Comment: The main difference between `\implies` and

Comment: Arturo is building the suspense...

Comment: Indeed! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidLewis You could use \kern; though it won't be perfect "\kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies" gives $ \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies$.

Comment: @DavidMitra  Perfect substitute for \nimplies